# Can't understand barrier code

Tags: java, multithreading, barrier

I ran across this barrier code and I cannot understand the `barrierPost` method.

Im supposed to use this code to solve an exercise where two teams of threads race eachother to count to 10000.

I don't understand why the same condition has different results which are opposite

```
public class Barrier {

    private int currentPosters = 0, totalPosters = 0;
    private int passedWaiters = 0, totalWaiters = 1;

    /**
     * @param totalPosters - Nr of threads required to start the waiting threads
     * @param totalWaiters - Nr of threads started later 
     */
     public Barrier (int totalPosters, int totalWaiters) {
     this.totalPosters = totalPosters; 
     this.totalWaiters = totalWaiters;

    }

    public synchronized void init(int i) {
        totalPosters = i; currentPosters=0;
    }

    public synchronized void barrierSet(int i) {
        totalPosters = i; currentPosters=0;
    } 

    public synchronized void barrierWait() {
        boolean interrupted = false;
        while (currentPosters = totalPosters) {
            try {wait();} 
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {interrupted=true;}
        }
        passedWaiters++;
        if (passedWaiters == totalWaiters) {
            currentPosters = 0; passedWaiters = 0; notifyAll();
        }
        if (interrupted) Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    public synchronized void barrierPost() {
        boolean interrupted = false;   // In case a poster thread beats barrierWait, keep count of posters.
        while (currentPosters == totalPosters) { 
            try {wait();} 
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {interrupted=true;}
        }
        currentPosters++;
        if (currentPosters == totalPosters) notifyAll();
        if (interrupted) Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you go into more detail about what you mean by "I don't understand why the same condition has different results which are opposite"?

Comment: It doesn't compile...

Comment: `currentPosters = totalPosters` -- will always true

Comment: nope, it doesn't compile, because the result isn't a `boolean`.

Comment: @AnthonyW  while (currentPosters = totalPosters) {
            try {wait();} 
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {interrupted=true;}
        }
        passedWaiters++;
        if (passedWaiters == totalWaiters) {
            currentPosters = 0; passedWaiters = 0; notifyAll();